# Why Quokka not showed [...Array]?

Tags: node.js, typescript, quokka.js

I have problem, that Quokka not showed result for this line:

```
[...Array(max - min + 1).keys()].map(i => i + min);
```

Below screenshot:
[image]
What is wrong, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should give a variable the result of the function as value, then reference it, like this:

```
const range = (min, max) =>
  [...Array(max - min + 1).keys()].map((i) => i + min);
let a = range(1, 5);
a;
```

This way it displays the result:

[image]

Calculating the value of it wont display the result by default.

Comment: Thank you, but I have still [], screenshot:
https://i.imgur.com/eQv6PUj.png

btw I using .ts files.

Comment: No, please look at the diffrent example:
https://i.imgur.com/CtIgfSo.png
ts-node return correct reuslt, but qukka, empty [], what is wrong?

Comment: It seems like you want to view the variable value in a function, with an input parameter. Because the input parameter could vary, i dont think that you can view the value of a variable in the scope of the function with quokka.
You could view the result like this:
let a = solution(inputArr);
a;

Comment: Or imagine what should Quokka display, if you call your function multiple times... Its not possible to display data inside the function scope.